# what namespace should I use to use Row method in .net

Tags: c#, excel

Namespace of Row could not be found

I have been trying to read cells of a particular column and compare data of the cell if it matches a string

```
private static int findRow(HSSFSheet sheet, String cellContent)
{
    int rowNum = 0; 
    for(Row row : sheet) 
    {
        for(Cell cell : row)
        {
            while(cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
            {
                if(cell.getRichStringCellValue().getString () == cellContent)
                {
                        rowNum = row.getRowNum();
                        return rowNum;  
                }
            }
        }
    }               
    return rowNum;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like valid C# code. What is `for (Row row : sheet)` supposed to do? Edit: It looks like Java code.

Comment: It looks like you've posted some Java code, as @John indicated. Be that the case, a quick Google search shows that the Row type you are interested in is likely this one: https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Row.html. If your question is actually about Java, consider adjusting the tags on your post so people can find it more easily.